# How to implement a data structure which takes an integer and its weight such that a query to it returns that integer its weight% times?

Tags: data-structures, tree, computer-science, implementation

Data is entered as the number followed by the weight. For example, if the data structure has data entered (1, 9) and (2, 1) then it should return the number 1 90% of the time and the number 2 10% of the time.

Which data structure should be used for this implementation? Also, what would the basic code for the query function look like?

Edit: I was considering a tree which stores the cumulative sum for every subtree. Say I have (1, 4), (2, 7), (3, 1), and (4, 11).
The tree would look like:
          23
         /   \
      11    12
      /  \  /  \
    4    7   1  11

I do not know if this tree should be binary. Also, does it make sense to store the weights in the tree and map them to the number or somehow use the numbers given as data input?

Comment: And where are you efforts and thoughts?

Comment: Yes, idea with cumulative sum is good. Do you need to add new values dynamically? If not, just use simple array with cumulative sums

Comment: The binary tree would work fine. Pick a random number between 0 and the cumulative sum, then just find where it goes via binary search. The final ranges in your example would be: `(0-4),(4,11),(11,12),(12,23)`. If it happens to be exactly `4,11, or 12`, just randomly pick one of the two. You need to track of the current sums so you know that the `1` is actually `13`. I agree with MBo if you not using random weights. Could also use an interval tree.

Comment: @Nuclearman Thank you! Could you provide me with an example case? I understand how to form the array. Also, we know that this query function should return value1 4/23 times, value2 7/23 times, value3 1/23 times and value4 11/23 times. And could you elaborate on the part about 1 being 13?

Comment: Elaboration: You know the cumulative total is `23`, so you pick a random number between `0 and 23`. Say this number turns out to be `13.5`, call it `n` to keep things short. The first node in your tree is `23`, and covers all numbers between `0 and 23`, `n` is between `0 and 23` so we continue down the tree. The left is 11 and represents `0 to 11` while the right is `12` and represents `11 + (0 to 12) = 11 to 23`, `n` is between that so we follow that node. Last, we have `1` which is `11 + (0 to 1) = 11 to 12` and `11` which is `11 + 1 + (0 to 11) = 12 to 23`. Since 13 in (12,23), return 11.

Comment: The logic for the bottom row is as followed: `4: 0 + 0 + (0 to 4) = (0 to 4)` (since it's the left most point, there is no offset. `7: 0 + 4 + (0 to 7) = 4 to 11`, the first is left, but the second is right, so only one offset. `1: 11 + 0 + (0 to 1) = 11 to 12`, again only one offset, but opposite this time. `11` is done above. The `13` in my above example was an error, as 1 is really only between `11 and 12`. The idea for offset calculation is to add the sum of the left sibling for the node followed, the value to add is `0`, if the node followed is the either the left child or the only child.

Answer (score 0):

Make from value/weight tuples `(1, 4), (2, 7), (3, 1), (4, 11)` an array with cumulative weight sums

```
[(1, 4), (2, 11), (3, 12), (4, 23)]
```

and get value with binary  search for cumulative weight field.

It is not clear from question, how the query should work - randomly?

Comment: This query function should return value1 4/23 times, value2 7/23 times, value3 1/23 times and value4 11/23 times. Similarly, if it runs 23 times, 1 is returned 4 times, etc. Do we rely on the randomize function here?

Comment: I don't know how these values should be distributed depending on query number - you have not specified yet

Comment: This method is best used if data does not change or can only be added. Removal of the first element in the array requires `O(N)` to re-calculate the sums. The binary tree approach requires `O(log N)`. I'm not sure `O(1)` per update is possible in general, though this method is as long as you don't remove elements. Also, for the randomization, you'd use `(0,4),(11,12),(12,23)` just the same as elaborated above, but it's much easier to search as it's just a binary search. The downside is slower updates for removal of points. Recommend this method if you don't need efficient removal.